# Hide place holder in ng-select when user enters text

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular9

I am trying to use [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources) with material design in my Angular 9 project for the autocomplete. By default, when the user entering the text ng-select shows the place holder at top of the autocomplete input field. However, I would like to hide the placeholder as soon as the user enters the text and show it when he clears the input field. Is there a way to achieve this using CSS? Project uploaded to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/pavankjadda/ng-select-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the search event provided by the element.  It'll provided you with the value of the input and in your case you only care if it has a value.  There exists a css solution, but this just felt cleaner.

In the html

```
<ng-select ...
   placeholder="{{myPlaceholder}}"
   (search)="onSearch($event)">
  </ng-select>
```

In the TS.

```
.
.
myPlaceHolder = "Select Person"
.
.
onSearch($event) {

 this.myPlaceHolder = $event.term == '': 'Select Person': '';
}
```